# Linking and cup products

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

The following is a problem in Munkres "Algebraic Topology" that I do not know how to tackle.  Let $A$ be the union of two once linked circles in $S^3$ and let $B$ be the union of two unlinked circles.  Show that the (integral) cohomology groups of $S^3 - A$ and $S^3 - B$ are isomorphic but the cohomology rings are not.

At this stage in the book Munkres has just defined cohomology and the cup product and done some hands on calculations so I think that is what he has in mind for this problem.  I am not sure if Munkres wants explicit triangulations and explicit cocyles generating the cohomology but this would be nice.

Comment: One space is homotopy equivalent to $S^1\times S^1$ and the other is the wedge of two circles and a sphere. You can compute cup products by hand to see they are different.